# How to use the singularize function in mutate?

Tags: r, text-processing, dplyr, corpus

I have a text corpus and as part of the preprocessing I need to singularize all words.

Let's say we have a corpus of words:

```
corpus <- c("house", "friends", "cats", "dogs") %>% tibble(word = .)
```

If I apply the singularize function (SemNetCleaner) directly it works, however I'd need to use a slow for-loop to apply it to every row of my words column:

```
#install.packages("SemNetCleaner")
library(SemNetCleaner)

corpus[2,1] %>% unlist() %>% singularize()

  word 
"friend"
```

However, if I use it within a mutate it just binds all entries like the paste() function:

```
corpus %>% mutate(singular = singularize(word))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  word    singular              
  <chr>   <chr>                 
1 house   house friends cats dog
2 friends house friends cats dog
3 cats    house friends cats dog
4 dogs    house friends cats dog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rowwise()

```
corpus %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(singular = singularize(word))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Rowwise: 
  word    singular
  <chr>   <chr>   
1 house   house   
2 friends friend  
3 cats    cat     
4 dogs    dog
```